# Как определить запущен ли поток? (С++ WINAPI)

Tags: c++, многопоточность, winapi

Поток запускает функцию проверки необходимости создания VPN-подключения, которая, в случае если VPN необходим, отрабатывает достаточно долго.
Для сокращения времени ожидания устанавливается время ожидания потока 3 секунды, по истечению которых нужно проверить работает ли всё ещё поток, и если да - прибить его и присвоить переменной нужное значение.

Код:

```
DWORD ThreadId;
HANDLE CheckAddressThread = CreateThread(NULL, 0, NeedVPN, NULL, 0, &ThreadId);
WaitForSingleObject(CheckAddressThread, 3000);
if(/*CheckAddressThread всё ещё отрабатывает...*/){
    TerminateThread(CheckAddressThread, 0);
    RequiredVPN = 1;
}
CloseHandle(CheckAddressThread);
if(RequiredVPN){...
```

Как проверить работает ли поток?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Результат WaitForSingleObject() как раз и будет соответствовать статусу потока: WAIT_OBJECT_0 - поток завершился, WAIT_TIMEOUT - поток активен, но Wait-функция ждала указанное время и вышла.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Недочитал MSDN...

Comment: @Iceman там неочевидно это написано, IMHO